# Merge lines that intersect postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql

These look like three straight lines that could have two endpoints at the extreme vertices

[image]

But in reality they are each longer linestrings that have endpoints that are on the interior of the line, basically the line folds in on itself

[image]

[image]

They started out as separate lines that were parallel, and I tried to join the ones that intersected by using this function:

```
ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))
```

where nl is the column of individual lines.

How can I change this query so I get a linestring made of 2 points where the endpoints are the expected endpoints from looking at the picture (the extreme vertices)

Alternatively, how can I take what I have after this point and turn it into what I want?

Here is an example line that I have:
"LINESTRING(-101.47751335594317 31.489023992956714,-101.46871182786654 31.488981396096023,-101.47866855724968 31.489029536221512,-101.46986702785048 31.488987023468102)"

and here is how it should be:
"LINESTRING(-101.46871182786654 31.488981396096023,-101.47866855724968 31.489029536221512)"
(before these endpoints were on the inside of the line)

Comment: This would be nicely solved by a `ST_MaximumDiameter` function - except that doesn't exist in PostGIS yet.

Comment: I think I solved it by using ST_LongestLine, about to test and then I'll post an answer if it works.

Comment: Right, `ST_LongestLine(A, A)` computes the maximum diameter of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using:

```
ST_LongestLine((ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))), (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))))
```

instead of:

```
ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(nl)))
```